# Printing numbers in a sequence given a condition using if and for statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to r and any help would be appreciated.

I want to get a sequence of numbers from 1 to 365 in certain steps.
when my first number starts from anything more than one, i want my code to print the number till/before 365 depending on the steps and then start from 1 again till it reaches the number it started from.

```
firstnumber=20
 steps=10
 lastnumber=0


     if(firstnumber > 1){lastnumber = 365 + firstnumber - (steps)}
     else{lastnumber = 365}

      for(number in seq(firstnumber, lastnumber, steps))
     {
    if(firstnumber > 1)
    { if(number + steps > 365)

    {number = (number + steps - 365)
      }
       }
       print(number)
     }
```

it should give me

```
 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,
 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170,
 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260,
 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340,
 350, 360, 5, 15
```

but it misses the 360 which is the last number before it goes to the start of the sequence 
Is something wrong with the if condition? or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Can you edit your post and make the expected output a little easier to read?

Comment: I wonder that it prints anything since you never defined date in your code...

Comment: It cant print the number 360, since your if statement if( number + steps > 365) triggers when number is greater than 355 (if you have a step size of 10).

Comment: I have edited my output, hope its clear now.

Comment: even if i change my step size to 2 it doesnt return the output which would be 10,12,14 and so on till it reaches 360 and then should print 2, 4... till 8. but here again it prints 358 but skips 360 and moves on to 2

Answer (score 3):

Modulo operator is always handy when you need the sequence of numbers to "wrap around".

```
firstnumber = 20
step = 10
limit = 365

seq(firstnumber - 1, limit + firstnumber - 1, step) %% limit + 1
#[1]  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230
#[23] 240 250 260 270 280 290 300 310 320 330 340 350 360   5  15
```

If instead of 1 to 365 range you want 0 to 364 range use this:

```
seq(firstnumber, limit + firstnumber, step) %% limit
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful

Comment: When i run the exact code as yours i get the sequence but instead of 365 i get a 0
`firstnumber = 10
step = 5
limit = 365
seq(firstnumber, limit + firstnumber, step) %% limit`

Comment: If you want your range to go from 1 to the limit inclusive (as opposed to 0 to one less than the limit) use `seq(firstnumber - 1, limit + firstnumber - 1, step) %% limit + 1.` I modified my answer to include this. Glad to help :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works exactly how I want it to.